# физика мяча при бросании под углом к горизонту

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx, box2d

Никак не выходит сделать адекватную физику мяча, https://ido.tsu.ru/schools/physmat/data/res/virtlab/text/m2_1.html по формулам вроде как все расчеты сделал, соответственно вычисляю x и y на каждом шагу,  и пользуюсь для запуска мяча setLinearVelocity(x,y),суть самой мысли начальной силы как в angry birds, т.е. натягивание и вылет мяча относительно силы натягивания, для этого использую методы touchup и touchdown в listener , x0 и y0 точки аргументы x и y метода touchUp.

Comment: Эм.. Ну там же все формулы есть...

Answer (score 4):

Если идеальная точность не требуется, то можно сделать так:

```js
var ball = document.querySelector('div');

var x = 0, y = 0, t = performance.now();
var g = 9.8 /* м/с^2 */ / 1000 / 1000 /* (мс/с)^2 */ * 2 /* px/м */;
var v = 100 /* px/с */ / 1000 /* с/мс */;
var a = Math.PI / 3 /* 60 deg */;
var vx = v * Math.cos(a), vy = v * Math.sin(a);

requestAnimationFrame(function draw() {
  var t1 = performance.now(), dt = t1 - t;
  
  x += vx * dt;
  y += (vy -= g * dt) * dt;
  t = t1;

  if (y < 0) {
    y = 0;
  }

  ball.style.transform = "translate(" + x + "px, " + y + "px)";

  if (y > 0) {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, main {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 16px;
}

main {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}

div {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<main><div></div></main>
```